2-Pole required for built-in circuit breakers in machines in countries without polarized plugs?
I build bespoke small run devices for export from the US.
These machines have DIN-rail assemblies with circuit breakers, power supplies, microcontrollers, etc.
We typically build in single pole circuit breakers on the live mains power inlet for technician safety and to protect against shorts. We usually use 2A 5A or 10A breakers depending on the device. This is, of course, in addition to the breakers in the wall panel.
We are now exporting to a country with German-style Type-F Schuko outlets, which are not polarized.
Since we are no longer able to know which wire is live vs neutral, is it the case that we should use two pole breakers?
My intuition is yes for two reasons.

To ensure there is not potential in the system during service when the technician has switched off the breaker
To ensure the entire device is de-energized in the event of a short to chassis or within the device wiring

Is using 2-pole breakers in devices a common practice in such countries*?
*Countries with type F: Austria, Germany, Greece, Italy, Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Turkey, Egypt, Iceland, Indonesia, Korea, Slovenia, Ukraine, and Vietnam
Type L: Chile, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Italy, Libya, Maldives, San Marino, Syrian Arab Republic, Tunisia, and Uruguay (included for search)

Do you specifically ask about breakers? Is it a normal situation to not unplug the device for service, but disconnect only with breaker? If there is only one breaker, would it make more sense to just add a two-pole mains switch instead of changing all breakers to two-pole? It might be that when you certify the device in Germany to be able to sell it, the certifying agency can surely tell you beforehand if you need to change anything before they start the certifying process so that it won't fail on simple stuff. If you are already exporting, the product must already have passed test, right?

In our industry, we don't actually get the devices certified. Each device is unique, and we are a small outfit. We use only CE listed components.
While it is normal to unplug a device for service, some technicians may simply flip the breaker.
I will edit my question to be clearer with regard to the service question vs the safety question.

I don't get how you manage to do that. I can of course as a consumer buy unsafe products like a phone charger from online marketplaces and start using them even if they have no certifications whatsoever and would be hazardous. Hazardous or not, without testing no EU store could legally sell those in EU to customers. It would not matter how small shop you run. Unless the devices for some reason are found to be exempt from CE mark. But CE mark means practically nothing, there are certifications that may be speficif for each country, such as GS mark in Germany. There are a lot of Directives.

In my experience fusing inside portable equipment (as opposed to a fixed, hard-wired setup) is normally designed to limit damage to the equipment due to internal component failure, as opposed to short to earth.
Short to earth is normally protected by upstream devices, which also protect the supply feed from switch board to the plug/receptable.
This is reflected in most domestic equipment using a two pole switch for isolation/switching, followed by a single pole protection device for limiting fault currents.
However, if this is for a commercial application, I would definitely consult the relevant standard for your target country, not least because you indemnity insurance is unlikely to be satisfied with a quote from EE.SE in the event of a problem.
